# $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} \geq \int_1^{n+1} \frac{1}{x} dx$ Inequality

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} \geq \int_1^{n+1} \frac{1}{x} dx$$

I don't see how you reach this inequality, or rather why it is correct.

The context of this problem was the following:

Show that $$a_n := \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} - \ln{n}$$ converges.

The prove that it is bounded, one can use the inequality above, to conclude that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} \geq \int_1^{n+1} \frac{1}{x} dx = \ln{(n+1)} \geq \ln{n}$$

Comment: For $x\in [k,k+1]$, we have $\frac{1}{x}\leq \frac{1}{k}$, so $\int_{k}^{k+1} \frac{1}{x} \leq \frac{1}{k}$ and the result follows by summing over $k$.

Comment: Careful, $\int_1^{n+1} \frac{1}{x} dx = \ln(n+1)$.

Comment: $1/x$ is strictly monotonically decreasing, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a function $g(x)$ as

$$g(x) = \begin{cases}1 & 1\leq x< 2\\
\frac12 & 2\leq x < 3\\
\vdots & \vdots\\
\frac1n& n\leq x< n+1\end{cases}$$

which is a piecewise continuous (therefore integrable) function and $g(x)\geq \frac1x$ for all $x\in[1,n+1]$.

Because $g(x)\frac1x$, you also know that

$$\int_1^{n+1} g(x)dx \geq \int_1^{n+1} \frac1x dx$$

Now, the integral of $g$ can be split into $n$ integrals of $g$, i.e.

$$\int_1^{n+1} g(x)dx = \int_1^2 g(x)dx + \int_2^3g(x)dx + \dots + \int_n^{n+1} g(x) dx$$
and $g$ is *constant* on all these intervals.

Answer (score 1):

By induction:

1. $n=1$. $$\sum_{k=1}^1\frac1k=1>\int_{1}^{2}\frac1x dx=\ln 2\approx 0.69$$
2. $n \to n+1$. Assume that the statement holds for $n\in \mathbb N$ and observe that $$\frac1{n+1}\int_{n+1}^{n+2}dx \ge \int_{n+1}^{n+2}\frac1xdx$$ since $\frac1x$ is decreasing on $[n+1,n+2]$. So \begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1k=\frac{1}{n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k&\ge \frac{1}{n+1}\int_{n+1}^{n+2}dx+\int_{1}^{n+1}\frac1x dx \\[0.2cm]&\ge \int_{n+1}^{n+2}\frac1x dx+\int_{1}^{n+1}\frac1x dx=\int_{1}^{n+2}\frac1x dx\end{align}